# Ajax - error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

So I'm having a problem with the usage of ajax and the standard html form submission (I'm developing in Django, but that's not relevant in this case).

Basicly, I have a button which calls a url to the browser (class="header-btn") -- as standard as possible -- and I have a js script that saves the mouse coordinates to the db (using .mousemove) via an ajax post. The position is sent to the db everytime I move my mouse, so you can see there are a LOT of requests being made. The problem is when I am moving my mouse (so requests are being made constantly) and then click the referred button I get this error in the server shell:

```
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 45187)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 582, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 323, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self) 
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 126, in __init__
    super(WSGIRequestHandler, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 640, in __init__
    self.finish()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 693, in finish
    self.wfile.flush()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 303, in flush
    self._sock.sendall(view[write_offset:write_offset+buffer_size])
error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

From what I've read in other posts (I may be wrong), this seems to be caused because there are ajax requests still being processed when the button submit was complete, and so the browser is already on a different page/url.

I wanted to know how to prevent this sort of behaviour. Should I take all the form submission (via button click) from the html to the js script? Am I totally wrong and there is a nice way to fix this?

My html and js are posted below.

Thanks in advance.

html:

```
<div id="header">
<table>
    <tr>
        <form class="header-form" action="{% url 'home:start' %}">{% csrf_token %}
            <td><button type="submit" class="header-btn"> dibbs</button></td>
        </form>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>

<form>
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div id="mouse" data-done-ref="{% url 'home:mousemove' %}"></div>
</form>

<div id="data"></div>
```

javascript:

```
function MousePosition(x,y){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    var currentMousePosition = new MousePosition(0,0);

    $("html").mousemove(function(event){
        currentMousePosition.x = event.pageX;
        currentMousePosition.y = event.pageY;
        $("#data").html("( "+event.pageX+" , "+event.pageY+" )");
        var data = JSON.stringify({
                csrfmiddlewaretoken: document.getElementsByName('csrfmiddlewaretoken')[0].value,
                x: currentMousePosition.x,
                y: currentMousePosition.y
        });
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost:8000/api/v1/position/",
            data: data,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            processData: false
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: A browser is limited to the number of simultaneous http connections it can use, I think that .mousemove will fire WAY too much and saturate the browser's available connections very quickly.  If you need this functionality I suggest you find a way to store and bundle the mouse x and y positions within Javascript so you can send a couple of hundred in one ajax request.  As an alternative, don't track every single movement of the mouse, just the "important" ones somehow.

Comment: I see. However, there could be a case when ajax was still sending a request by the time I clicked the html button, right? Would that be a problem?

Comment: Yes that can definitely happen.  It seems like your javascript doesn't care about any response from the ajax call, so perhaps just trap this error in your server script and assume that the browser went away to another page, but you should be able to still store the info in your database.

Comment: I'm a js newby, can you give me some insight on how I would do it?

Comment: Trapping the error in your server script would be done in python/django.  There should be a way to abort the response if there is an error.  I can't help you with python, sorry.

Comment: Ok, I will try to check that. Thanks for your feedback ;)